# How to combine the bump maps of two texture maps?

Tags: node-editor, bump

[image: Node Configuration]
[image: Rendered image with no cuneiform signs]
[image: Rendered image with cuneiform signs]
[image: Cuneiform sign template]

I give a clay texture map (downloaded online) to the 3d model, it gives the colour of the model, then the roughness input and finally the normal input (non color data for the last two inputs).

I also want to imprint the grayscale template with cuneiform signs placed on the 3d model, I do this by giving the template as a normal input(for the last image texture I give the b/w template image). But as you can see, the rendered image with the signs dont have the small texture/bump variations of the clay texture map (looks flat).

**How do I go about combining the height input for bump node of the clay texture and b/w template for the given node configuration?**

I am using cycles render, also if possible want to do it using blender node editor rather than manually combining the normal maps of the two images using some other software.

I have tried the answers given in the following link [How to Combine two Normal Maps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38298/how-to-combine-two-normal-maps) but it hasn't worked out.

Comment: You asked an exelent question and have the perfekt answer :) Please edit your answer out of your question. Its absolutley fine to anser your own question and then mark it as the correct answer so this question gets closed.

Comment: Please note that you are using bump maps (black and white images) and not normal maps, which consist of color information. That is why the answer on the link does not work. Read: [Bump Maps vs Normal Maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63053/bump-maps-vs-normal-maps/63058#63058)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/multiple-texture-displacements-mapping-in-one-scene/44927#44927

Answer (score 4):

Nvm I think I solved my issue by using a Mix RGB node to combine the heights of both the images as shown below.

[image: nodes]