# Mask Map Displacement

Tags: texturing, node-editor, displacement, masking, bump

I'm making a Brick Wall texture, from the Rob Tutyel course. The main problem with this wall is the Sandstone border. It's just bulging way too much.

[image]

I hope you can see that hard transition with the Sandstone.

[image]

Here is the hard line, it's really weird and un-realistic.

I've learned why this problem occurs. I'm using a mask maps to tell Blender where and where not do the Brick Wall displacement. For the part where it isn't supposed to do displacement, it just over does it. I'm not sure if there is some sort of "null" node. But it would sure as hell be useful right now.

[image]

Here is Sandstone mask map. I had to take a snippet of it, because the file size is way to large.

I am aware that the plaster is using the Brick Wall displacement. I was trying to solve one of them, because they are both basically the same thing.

Here is my [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d84c475do3bsvb7/Brick%20Wall.blend?dl=0)

Here is a screenshot of nodes related to the mask map.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/multiple-texture-displacements-mapping-in-one-scene and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144017/how-to-combine-the-bump-maps-of-two-texture-maps?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the strength and distance on the Bump Node.https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/bump.html?highlight=bump%20node

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger They reduce the displacement itself. I'm trying to make the Sandstone less visible, but in the process it reduces the Brick Wall displacement too.

Comment: @susu I tried to do some of the things that were mentioned in the post, but it didn't solve my problem. There is still the hard transition.

Comment: Have you tried setting the white stop of your color ramp to a darker value ?

Comment: @Gorgious Yeah, it didn't work. If you want to play around with the Brick Wall, I included the download. I tried everything I know, but I'm still pretty new to nodes.